# Have a problem with disqus setting to make it work on my website

Tags: html, disqus

I’m trying to install Disqus on my website but it’s not working. it seems that I haven't set it the good way.

I have just a blank part, as you can see on :

34.207.144.128/tweets.html.

Here is my code, did I do something wrong?

Can someone help me, it is for my school application;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="behavior.js"></script>
    <title>                                                                              
      Aouni Karim webpages                                                               
    </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <link href="https://apply.holbertonschool.com/level2/school.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <body class="works_on_smartphone">
    <a href="https://apply.holbertonschool.com"target="blank" >
      <img src="https://apply.holbertonschool.com/holberton-logo.png">
          </a>
    <header>
      <ul><a href="http://34.207.144.128/whatsableton.html"> What is ableton ?</a></ul>
      <ul><a href="http://34.207.144.128/whenitwascreate.html">When it was create ?</a><\
/ul>
      <ul><a href="http://34.207.144.128/whychooseableton.html">Why choose ableton ?</a>\
</ul>
    </header>
    <main>
      <article>
        <h1> WHAT IS ABELETON LIVE ?</h1>
        <img src="https://img.audiofanzine.com/images/u/product/normal/ableton-live-11-s\
tandard-288625.png"id="smart_thumbnail" >
    <p>
      Ableton live is a DAW, a digital audio workstation. A software allowing to recordi\
ng, to edit, to manipulate, to create and to play digital audio content which can be lyr\
ics , music or sound effects. They allow the mixing of several audio tracks on a time gr\
id. You can use audio effect such as filter, delay or reverb to create more creative sou\
nd. Feel free to learn more on <a href="https://www.ableton.com/"target="blank" >Ableton\
 live.</a></p>
    <h2>When it was create ?</h2>
    <p>
      Ableton was founded in Germany in 1999. The first version of Live appeared on the \
market in 2001. The company is made up of about fifty people, including computer enginee\
rs, marketing specialists. The company is managed by Gerhard Behles and Bernd Roggendorf\
, its founders, and Jan Bohl. Most of Ableton's employees are involved in both productio\
n and creation of music.</p>
    <h3>Why choose Ableton live ?</h3>
    <p>
      Ableton live contains a navigation panel for easily reaching all sound, effect, and\
 instrument packs. There are 2 views: the session screen and the arrangement screen. The\
 session screen allows you to order clips and is therefore organized around loops. The \
arrangement screen can be used live to record all the scenes of the session. It allows you\
u to control the parameters of the tracks (plugins, effects). Ableton live already inclu\
des effects but it are possible to download standard effects: VST.</p>
        <p>
          Ableton's ergonomics make it a very flexible and easy-to-access software. Effe\
ct or instrument can be added to it by a simple drag and drop. We can use it in an amate\
ur way but it has all the features that professionals will appreciate.</p>
      </article>
      <aside>
        <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
        <script>
          var disqus_config = function () {
          this.page.url = 34.207.144.128/tweets.html;  // Replace PAGE_URL with your pag\
e's canonical URL variable
          this.page.identifier = aouni_karim; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page'\
s unique identifier variable
          };
          (function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
          var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
          s.src = 'https://http-34-207-144-128-tweets-html.disqus.com/embed.js';
          s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
          (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
          })();
        </script>
        <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_\
noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
      </aside>
      <footer>
        <p>Made by Karim Aouni for <a href="https://apply.holbertonschool.com" target="_\
blank">Holberton School</a>.</p>
      </footer>
    </main>
  </body>
  </html>
```

As you can see There seem to be a couple of lines that haven’t been enclosed, so my HTML, and technically Disqus, isn’t able to recognize it.

Can someone explain to me what can I do?

thanks

thanks

Comment: i change my name to have the right username but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your string values in quotations `''` in your `disqus_config` function of your inline JavaScript. Without the quotations JavaScript will interpret your strings as variables that are undefined.

i.e. `'aouni_karim'` instead of `aouni_karim`

```js
let name = 'aouni_karim'
// vs
let name = aouni_karim
```

Try this:

```html
<script>
  var disqus_config = function () {
    this.page.url = '34.207.144.128/tweets.html';
    this.page.identifier = 'aouni_karim';
  };
  (function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
  var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
  s.src = 'https://http-34-207-144-128-tweets-html.disqus.com/embed.js';
  s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
  (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: please help me , i enclosed the page url and identifier but it's still not working !